# Dynamically load all images from folder/subfolders with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `/img` directory on my Github Pages website. There are about 50 images in `/img` and sub folders that I want to display in a grid on a page. I have no interest in typing out the following 50 times for each image...

```
  <a href="...">
     <img alt=".." src="img/...">
  </a>
```

... especially since I will be adding and removing images over time.

How do dynamically create the HTML code with JavaScript? I obviously can't use PHP since this is Github Pages.

I have already tried AJAX and requirejs but couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using [Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions)

In your repository add a new file `update-image-list.yml` under path `.github/workflows/` (you may need to create the folders)

Put this code into the file:

```
name: Update Image List
on:
  push
jobs:
  updateImageList: # you can put any name here
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 # Checkout repo
      - shell: bash
        run: ls -Rpm1 ./img/ > images.txt # Saving file list into a file
      - name: Save changes
        uses: actions-go/push@v1 # pushing the changes to the repo
        with:
          force: true
          commit-files: images.txt
          commit-message: Updating image list
```

Now, every time you push something to your repo this script will be executed saving an up-to-date list of the image files into `images.txt` file using `ls` command line and then pushing the file to the repo. The content will be something like:

**images.txt**

```
./img/:
image1.jpg
child-folder/
image2.png
image3.jpg

./img/child-folder:
image4.jpg
```

Now that you have the list of image files into `images.txt`, you just have to get the file to the frontend side and process its content

Something like this works:

**In your HTML:**

```
<div class="images" id="images"></div>

<script>
function loadImages() {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            const fileList = this.responseText.split('\n'); // Split by lines
            let currentFolder = '';

            const filePaths = fileList
                .map(f => { // Build correct path for each file
                    let filePath = '';

                    if (f) {
                        if (f[0] === '.') {
                            currentFolder = f.replace('.', '').replace(':', '/');
                        }
                        else if (f[f.length - 1] !== '/') {
                            filePath = `${location.href}${currentFolder}${f}`;
                        }
                    }
          
                    return filePath;
                })
                .filter(f => f); // Remove empty lines
      
            const imagesContainer = document.getElementById('images');
      
            filePaths.map(f => { // Create and put images to the DOM
                const img = document.createElement('IMG');
                img.src = f;
                imagesContainer.appendChild(img);
            });
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "images.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

loadImages();
</script>
```

But of course you can use any library/framework to do the same